# List of Values in ADF service interface

Tags: web-services, oracle-adf

I got a ADF Business Components Model Project. In some View Objects I defined a List of Values for the Attributes, and also set a Label in the UI Hints tab of some Attributes.
When I run the Application Module every thing works fine.

Now I want to expose this (and some other) View Objects via web service. So I added a Service Interface to the Application Module, where I set how the View Objects should be exposed. I also checked the Generate Control Hints Operation Check box.

In the next step I create a Web Service Data Control with the WSDL of my service. Then when I drop the result of a, for example,  findByViewCriteria-method, to a jsf page, and choose ADF Form, I got neither the option for a Choice component, nor are the labels like I configured them.

Does any one have a idea, what am I missing? How do I enable the LOV and UI Hints in my web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shays answer was very helpful (as always), though I want to share how I eventually solved this in my case.
As he pointed out

> The Web service won't have LOV defined on it just because those are defined in the ADF BC layer.

So I dropped the attribute, as `selectOneChoise` to the page. Important thing to note is, that only the result of a `find`-method can be used as a `List Data Source`, the result of a `getByKey`-method results in an error.

Answer (score 0):

The Web service won't have LOV defined on it just because those are defined in the ADF BC layer.
So what you need to do is to add a list to the parameter you are passing to a Web service.
Similar to this:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/adding_lov_to_non_database

Comment: I don't get the choice of "ADF LOV input" when I'm doing this with an web service data control